# Limiting an EditText in Android by text width instead of number of characters

Tags: android, android-edittext

I am trying to fit an `EditText` into different `ImageView` templates. For each template, I want to restrict the `EditText` to a specific width.

For example, in one of my templates, the `EditText` field should fit a maximum of 300 pixels wide, so I would like to set the text width limit to 300 pixels.

However, I cannot restrict the length by character length because, typing:

"iiiiiii" is not the same width as "wwwwwwwwww."

Would anyone happen to have a solution to this? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a textWatcher. This would have a method called onTextChanged(). You could override this to get the length. Once this is done, you could alter the length of the textView   itself.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.rqna.net/qna/tssiw-android-edittext-limit-string-length-not-by-characters.html

That guy answered your question with probably the best answer 2 months ago...

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve something similar with `android:paddingRight` through xml